# Net flux calculation through a cube

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, gauss-law

[image]

Ans:
Applying Gauss’s law the net ﬂux can be calculated. And for option (B), I guess the flux will be 0. But not sure. Can anyone explain all the 3 options?

For left and rignt face,  EA = 300*(0.05)^2 = 0.75 Nm^2/c , but this does not match with the answer.
And for top, bottom, front and back i guess it should be 0.

Comment: Can you please provide a clearer image?

Comment: Is this your homework?

Answer (score 2):

First, we must represent the electric field vector
$$
 \begin{align}
    \mathbf{E} &= E \cos{\theta}\,\hat{\mathbf{x}} - E \sin{\theta}\,\hat{\mathbf{y}}
 \end{align}
$$

Calculating the flux over the given surface using the definition of the flux
$$
    \Phi_{E} \equiv \int_{\mathcal{S}}\, \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{a} 
$$

Let's, we give an index to the surfaces
$$
 \begin{align}
(i) &\rightarrow \mathrm{front, \, parallel\,to\,}xy\mathrm{-plane} \\ 
(ii) &\rightarrow \mathrm{right, \, parallel\,to\,}yz\mathrm{-plane}  \\
(iii) &\rightarrow \mathrm{up, \, parallel\,to\,}zx\mathrm{-plane} \\
(iv) &\rightarrow \mathrm{bottom, \, parallel\,to\,}zx\mathrm{-plane} \\
(v) &\rightarrow \mathrm{left, \, parallel\,to\,}yz\mathrm{-plane} \\
(vi) &\rightarrow \mathrm{back, \, parallel\,to\,}xy\mathrm{-plane}
 \end{align}
$$

(a) The flux through each cube face
$$
 \begin{align}
    \Phi_{tot, E} &= \oint_{\mathcal{S}} \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{a} \\
    &=
     \int_{(i)} (0)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y + 
     \int_{(ii)} (E\cos{\theta})\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z + 
     \int_{(iii)} (-E\sin{\theta})\,\mathrm{d}z\,\mathrm{d}x + \\
    &\quad 
     \int_{(iv)} -(-E\sin{\theta})\,\mathrm{d}z\,\mathrm{d}x + 
     \int_{(v)} -(E\cos{\theta})\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z + 
     \int_{(vi)} -(0)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y \\
    &=
     \left[\quad 0 \quad \right]_{(i)} + 
     \left[\,\,\, E\cos{\theta}\int\limits_{z=0}^a \,\, \int\limits_{y=0}^a  \mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y \,\,\,\right]_{(ii)} + 
     \left[\,\,\, -E\sin{\theta}\int\limits_{x=0}^a \,\, \int\limits_{z=0}^a  \mathrm{d}z\,\mathrm{d}x \,\,\,\right]_{(iii)} + \\
    &\quad
     \left[\,\,\, E\sin{\theta}\int\limits_{x=0}^a \,\, \int\limits_{z=0}^a  \mathrm{d}z\,\mathrm{d}x \,\,\,\right]_{(iv)} +
     \left[\,\,\, -E\cos{\theta}\int\limits_{z=0}^a \,\, \int\limits_{y=0}^a  \mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y \,\,\,\right]_{(v)} +
     \left[\quad 0 \quad \right]_{(vi)} \\
    &= 
     \left[\quad 0 \quad \right]_{(i)} +
     \left[\quad a^2 E\cos{\theta} \quad \right]_{(ii)} +
     \left[\quad -a^2 E\sin{\theta} \quad \right]_{(iii)} + \\
    &\quad
     \left[\quad a^2 E\sin{\theta} \quad \right]_{(iv)} +
     \left[-\quad a^2 E\cos{\theta} \quad \right]_{(v)} +
     \left[\quad 0 \quad \right]_{(vi)}
 \end{align}
$$

(b) Net flux through the entire surface. Summing the result in part (a)
$$
    \Phi_{tot,E} = 0
$$

(c) The electron was placed at, $\mathbf{r}' = -2a\hat{\mathbf{x}} + \dfrac{a}{2}\hat{\mathbf{y}} + \dfrac{a}{2}\hat{\mathbf{z}}$. Then the electric field due to the electron 
$$
 \begin{align}
    \mathbf{E}_e &= \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{e}{\left| \mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}' \right|^3} \left( \mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}' \right) \\
     &= \frac{e}{4\pi\epsilon_0} 
    \frac{(x - x')\mathbf{\hat{x}} + (y - y')\mathbf{\hat{y}} + (z - z')\mathbf{\hat{z}}}{\left[ (x - x')^2 + (y - y')^2 + (z - z')^2 \right]^{3/2}}
 \end{align}
$$

Using Gauss' theorem, we find that the net flux through the entire
$$
 \begin{align}
    \Phi_{tot,e} &= \oint_{\mathcal{S}} \mathbf{E}_e \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{a} \\
     &= \int_{\mathcal{V}} ( \nabla \cdot \mathbf{E}_e)\,\mathrm{d}\tau \\
     &= 0
 \end{align}
$$
Since the divergence of $\mathbf{E}_e$ equal to 0. For detail see the below explanation

$$
 \begin{align}
    \frac{\partial E_{e,x}}{\partial x} &= |\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|^{-3} + 3(x-x')^2 |\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|^{-5},\\
    \frac{\partial E_{e,y}}{\partial y} &= |\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|^{-3} + 3(y-y')^2 |\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|^{-5},\\
    \frac{\partial E_{e,z}}{\partial z} &= |\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|^{-3} + 3(z-z')^2 |\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|^{-5}
 \end{align} 
$$

Summing all three partial derivative, we know that $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E}_e = 0$

N.B. : $a = 5 \times 10^{-2}\,\mathrm{m}$, $\theta = 30^{\circ}$, and $E = 300\,\mathrm{N/C}$